# Tables do not show in QGIS PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I've created user profiles for my teammates to connect to my postGIS database with QGIS.

with my own user account I am able to successfully connect to my postGIS database on AWS RDS using QGIS 2.18.

user creation SQL:

```
CREATE USER foobar WITH
    LOGIN
    NOSUPERUSER
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    INHERIT
    NOREPLICATION
    CONNECTION LIMIT -1
    PASSWORD 'xxxxxx';
```

And granted permissions:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA test TO foobar;
```

Am I missing a step? When I connect in QGIS, I only see an empty public schema. [image]

EDIT: In addition to the accepted answer, one can also change the default privileges so newly created tables are shown automatically in QGIS:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA test GRANT ALL ON TABLES to foobar;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to grant usage on your schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test TO foobar;
```

Comment: If for some reason PostGIS extension has been installed under different schema than the default public then the user also needs access to that schema. For example, if the PostGIS extension has been installed under the schema postgis then one has to run the query: `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA postgis TO foobar;`. I am not sure, why one would use different than the public schema for the PostGIS extension but probably there can be reasons.